# How to prevent R from dropping groups of size 0

Tags: r

I am running the following code to count the amount of days that sites are over 90.

```
temp2 <- temp %>%
    filter(ds > '2017-12-31') %>%
    filter(over90 == 1) %>%
    group_by(site) %>%
    tally()
```

However, this drops sites which do not have days over 90. I want my output to include these sites with a value of zero, instead of simply not existing. Any way I can do this?

Pretend data:

```
site over90
a    1
a    0
a    1
b    0
```

What happens:

```
site n
a    2
```

What I want:

```
site n
a    2
b    0
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Why not just remove your filter() and instead add the variable to your group_by() statement? E.g., group_by(over90, site).

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Why don't you just do `df <- rbind(temp2, c('b', 0))`

Comment: @CoreyLevinson It's very likely that OP has simplified the question, such that adding a single row is not viable. In their real code, they may have 30 different values for `site` that do not have any values of `over_90` equal to 1, which you would not want to manually add.

Answer (score 2):

If your `site` is a factor variable you can use `tidyr::complete` to fill in the blanks at the end:

```
filter(dd, over90 == 1) %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  complete(site, fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
    site     n
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      a     2
2      b     0
```

---

data

```
dd <- read.table(text = 
"site over90
a    1
a    0
a    1
b    0",
header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I appreciate that `tidyr::complete` will do the job. But I'm just wondering that if `site` is factor (rather we can change it `factor`) then even `table` function can be an alternative. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: Yeah, your answer demonstrates that quite well. `table` is nice because it's built in to base and simplifies the workflow. `table` isn't nice because it returns a `table` object instead of a data frame (which will be a multidimensional array if there are more columns).

Comment: Also takes about 10x longer to execute using `table` according to the benchmarks I just ran. Mean times in ms: `{gregor: 37.9, brittenb: 38.4, mkr: 366.7}`

Comment: @brittenb I get much faster times with `table` using it directly. I think using it on a data frame slows it down, but if you just do `filter(dd, over90 == 1) %>% with(table(site, over90))` it is more than 10x faster than the other methods.

Comment: What if my site is not a factor variable?

Comment: Then you should convert it to a factor variable before using my answer.

Comment: I converted it, and I am getting an error: Error in group_by(site) : object 'site' not found

Comment: That would happen if you are not passing a data frame with a column named `"site"` into `group_by`. Without seeing your code, I can't tell you whether you're passing a different data frame (or no data frame) in, or if you are just using a different column name, but it is one of those two issues.

Answer (score 1):

`tally` isn't doing quite what you want it to. Since you just want to count the number of rows where `over_90` is equal to one and that variable is binary, you can sum that column to get the effect of counting.

```
df = data_frame(site=sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace=TRUE),
                over_90=sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE))
df
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#    site over_90
#   <chr>   <int>
# 1     c       0
# 2     b       1
# 3     c       0
# 4     b       0
# 5     c       1
# 6     b       0
# 7     a       0
# 8     a       1
# 9     c       1
#10     c       0

df$over_90[df$site == 'c'] = 0
df %>% group_by(site) %>% summarise(n = sum(over_90))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   site     n
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1     a     1
#2     b     1
#3     c     0
```

Comment: This is an intelligent option not sure about performance though. You can update your answer considering sample data from OP.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `table` instead. But you have first convert `site` in `factor` so that count for all factors is included after calling `table` function.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(site = as.factor(site)) %>%   #This line is very important. 
  filter(over90 ==1) %>%                               
  group_by(site) %>%
  table()

# site 1
# a    2
# b    0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"site over90
a    1
a    0
a    1
b    0",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```